# How to split string in java based on period `.`

Tags: java

Here I input a string where user inputs filename with extension and i want to write a program that gives out the extension of the file but when I run this program it gives exception arrayindexoutofbound exception, any reason why?

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Extensionfile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter file with data type");
        String file = sc.next();
        String parts[] = file.split(".");
        String part1 = parts[1];
        System.out.println("The file type is"+part1);

    }
}
```

Comment: `file.split("\\.");` `.` is any character in regex. And after that check if you have atleast one element in `parts`

Comment: [`FilenameUtils.getExtension(String)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getExtension%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: This code has a bug. Filenames themselves can contain periods

Answer (score 6):

Since period `.` is predefined character class in java regular expressions, you should use in below way

```
String parts[] = file.split("\\.");
```

or

```
String parts[] = file.split("[.]");
```

check here for more information [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)